# Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email

I'm using below code for sending mail. It's working fine in gmail server, but it's not working for my domain.
It's showing an error like

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.999servers.com'

How can I solve this issue?
This is my code so far:

```
require("PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
require("PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "mail.mydomain.in";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "mail";
$mail->Password = "password";

$mail->SetFrom($admin_user_mail);
$mail->AddAddress($login_user_mail);
$mail->AddCC($admin_user_mail);
$mail->Subject = "Mail Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail Content";


if($mail->send()) 
{   
    echo "Mail Send";
} else 
{
    echo "Mail Not sent";
}
```

Comment: Does your mail server support TLS or even SSL

Comment: Yes its support both TLS and SSL.

Comment: It looks like your SMTP server has an out of date or invalid TLS certificate.

Comment: Hi tadman. How can I solve this issue. What I want to change in my code or else I want to change in server setting?

Comment: Hi, still I can't able to solve this issue. Almost last two days I'm trying with this code still mail not sending. kindly let me know the solution if any one know.

Answer (score 9):

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
       'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );
```